# How to correctly set accessibilityFrame of UIAccessibilityElement?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uikit

I watched the WWDC session about accessibility and did how Apple recommends:

```
// Convert frame to window coordinates
frame = [view convertRect:frame toView:[appDelegate window]];

// Convert frame to "screen" coordinates
frame = [w convertRect:frame toWindow:nil];

DLog(@"accessibilityFrame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(frame));

// Set accessibility frame
element.accessibilityFrame = frame;
```

My accessibility container object is created in -viewDidLoad of a view controller.
It then creates UIAccessibilityElement objects for items on a map image.

The problem:

When I call the code after some delay, everything is OK. The correct accessibilityFrame looks like this:

```
{{0, 184}, {44, 200}}
```

When I call the above code in -initWithFrame: of my accessibility container view, -convertRect:toWindow: divides all values by 2. The frame becomes smaller and wrong. The wrong accessibilityFrame looks like this:

```
{{0, 220}, {22, 100}}
```

It seems the -convertRect:toWindow: method has a bug that makes it work incorrectly when called too fast after -applicationDidFinishLaunching... Is there a workaround to safely get it converted to the correct screen coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `UIAccessibilityConvertFrameToScreenCoordinates`?
This is a function that takes a `CGRect` and a `UIView`, and will convert the rect to `UIScreen` coordinates from the `UIView's` coordinate space.